# URL rewriting and DNS translate

Tags: url

Fellow sufferers!

I want to have human-understandable links into Sharepoint. My project is a few levels down into the SharePoint folders, so I want to be able to link like: HTK/Test/Testcases/Performancetest/Testreport.doc

(project name is HTK, then I have a folder Test and so on)

Is Sharepoint able to help me by understanding that "HTK" should be replaced by a path? I will probably have to involve our DNS server as well.

Please give me some ideas to proceed?

Comment: what you mean but remove the HTK to path...can you tell us what is current url and what you want after?

Comment: I want to use 'HTK' as the beginning of the URL because thats the project name. After that, I want to put the path under that project.

Answer (score 1):

"Symmetrical" rewriting is supported - for example, rewriting...

mysite.com/subsite1/subsite2/page.aspx

to

mynewsite.com/subsite1/subsite2/pages.aspx

However, "assymetrical" rewriting is NOT supported - for example, rewriting

mysite.com/subsite1/subsite2/page.aspx

to

mynewsite.com/subsite2/pages.aspx

For more information:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2818415

Comment: 302 Redirects are always supported, but this is not rewriting the URL - it is actually sending the client to the "true" (and maybe unfriendly) URL.  They can be effective for Vanity URLs though.